# Change highlighted and cursor color for whole application?

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the highlighted and cursor color for whole application?

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/home_background_color</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".AppName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

but the highlighted and cursor color are not changed.

Comment: are you added same style  in values-v21 styles?

Comment: I don't have values-21, but values, values-v11 and values-v14 and I have put exactly same style to 3 of them.

Answer (score 3):

You must set colorPrimary and colorAccent attributes to your app theme.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorPrimary">color you want HEX</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">color you want HEX</color>
<color name="colorAccent">color you want HEX</color>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the cursor color by changing the colorAccent in your styles file.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

i'm not sure about the minimum sdk version with which it should work with, but it works for marshmallow for me.